# T-sql: Cannot see why IF clause never gets called

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like this:

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Scores](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Score] [float] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Scores] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

And I have some INSERTs

```
INSERT INTO Scores (Score) VALUES ( 0.5)
INSERT INTO Scores (Score) VALUES ( 2)
INSERT INTO Scores (Score) VALUES ( 3)
INSERT INTO Scores (Score) VALUES ( 4.5)
```

Then I realize that I need to change all scores where 0.5 should be 2 etc.
So, I use a cursor to help me with that. Like this:

```
DECLARE @id int  
DECLARE @score float
DECLARE myCursor CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR     

SELECT Id, Score      
FROM [dbo].[Scores]
OPEN myCursor FETCH NEXT FROM myCursor INTO @id, @score 
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN     
    PRINT 'Id: ' PRINT @id    
    PRINT 'Score: ' PRINT @score       
    -- do your tasks here      
    FETCH NEXT FROM myCursor INTO @id, @score

    IF @score = 2 
    BEGIN 
        UPDATE Scores set Score = 3.0 WHERE Id = @id
    END
    IF @score = 3 
    BEGIN 
        UPDATE Scores set Score = 4.0 WHERE Id = @id
    END
    IF @score = 0.5
    BEGIN 
        UPDATE Scores set Score = 2.0 WHERE Id = @id
    END
    IF @score = 4.5
    BEGIN
        UPDATE Scores set Score = 5.0 WHERE Id = @id
    END
END  
CLOSE myCursor DEALLOCATE myCursor
```

Before you propose a nicer solution, please tell me why 
this row never gets called:

```
UPDATE Scores set Score = 2.0 WHERE Id = @id
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Update Scores
Set Score = 
  case 
    when Score = 0.5 then 2
    when Score = 4.5 then 5
    --etc...
    else Score
  end;
```

Edit: Sorry, missed the point of it.

Answer is because the fetches are wrong.
Put the

```
FETCH NEXT FROM myCursor INTO @id, @score
```

At the bottom of the cursor loop. You are fetching row 1 once outside the loop and once again at the top (but after printing out the values).

Comment: "Before you propose a nicer solution, please tell me why this row never gets called:"

Comment: Although SQL has trouble optimising and cursors. If you don't have any explicit reason for cursors, I'd stick with the update and case solution I posted.

Comment: Good eye...  +1 (more chars...)

Comment: I'd already created the table to test if my update...case was syntactically correct. So it was easy to test then it was obvious ;)

Comment: Hi all 
I have moved Fetch next as proposed by DaveShaw. It works.
I still need the cursor, because in real life I need to update approx 1000 rows which has the wrong score. 
But if you are good at sql you can show me how to solve this with CTEs.

Thanks all....

Answer (score 0):

Rounding error is a possibility.  What happens if you try declaring Score as a decimal column (and variable) rather than as a float?

Comment: There shouldn't be any such problem with the number `2` I would have thought.

Comment: Actually the test is `IF @score = 0.5` not `2` but the same applies as this is easily represented in binary.